# Rounded corners for navbar?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

For example, I can use this

```
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px
```

To give the HTML5 element, such as a button, a round corner instead of a normal angular corner

Can I do the same for navbar?

The below is awesome but I am just curious if I can give the round corners to a navbar.  If not then it is ok it is not overwhelmingly important

```
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" id=viewtherecent> Recent </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" id=viewthefrequency> Frequent </a> </li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: Have you given it a try? What was the result? I think you can (almost) any HTML element a border radius.

Comment: I did but it is not giving me border radius.  You can see for yourself.

Comment: How did you try it? If you only apply the `-webkit-border-radius: 30px` you won't see it. http://jsfiddle.net/sLwwzf6r/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Im not sure if you mean the buttons in the navbar or the Navbar itself so i provided 2 demos.

**Demo** rounded buttons

http://jsfiddle.net/r10tjkuz/

[image]

**CSS**

```
 .nav-border {
    border-radius: 30px;    
    }
```

**Demo** rounded Navbar

http://jsfiddle.net/6y1294rv/

[image]

**CSS**

```
  .nav-bordera {
    border-top-left-radius:30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:30px;   
    }

    .nav-borderb {
    border-top-right-radius:30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:30px;  
    }
```

Comment: Or use `:first-child` and `:last-child`.

Comment: or do that yeah, forgot about the child's  :))

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Add a CSS class to your navbar and set border radius:

```
<div class="navbar" data-role="navbar"></div>

.navbar {
     border-radius: 30px;
}
```

If you don't want to add a class you can use CSS attribute selectors (but I don't usually style things like this).

```
[data-role=navbar] { 
     border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeap or if vendor prefixes are THAT important to you -- as they appear to be:

```
[data-role=navbar] {
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using bootstrap 4 then you can do it by adding this to your css :

```
.header-dark .navbar {

border-radius:25px;
```

}